# Facebook API : Can I get user's public URL in v2

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

In v1 we can get user public link

/v1.0/me

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.link);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.link';
    });
  }
```

result will be https://www.facebook.com/user_id

but in v2

/v2.0/me

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.link);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.link';
    });
  }
```

result will be https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/814241178599786/

Is that possible to get public URL from Facebook API? If yes then how?

Thank You

Comment: I think according to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user) documentation, you can use the response.link value, but you need to have public_profile permission.

Comment: public_profile is a default permission given to every app when a user signs up. It will not give you the real link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Graph v2.0, this is **not** possible. The reason for this is that Facebook are trying to provide users with more data security.

As you mentioned, the app scoped user URL https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/814241178599786/ will redirect to their profile page.

Also note that you can't get:

- The user's actual Facebook ID
- The user's username